# Show Image Instead of Video on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm making this website with video effects (like [this](https://wonchondev.web.app/images/video/cross-platform.mp4)) instead of images. I've added code like this:

```
<video muted autoplay playsinline src="path_to_video.mp4"></video>
```

However, iOS doesn't support the `autoplay` property, which makes the video stuck on its first frame. I want to display a alternative image instead of the video on iPhones and browsers that don't support `autoplay`.

Is there a way to do this? (with JavaScript of possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're checking for the system not the screen ratio, then you can use **navigator** property.

and adjust your code to be like this

```
<video id="video-img" muted autoplay playsinline src="path-to-video"></video>
```

and in your js script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
    $('#video-img').replaceWith('<img src="path-to-img" >');
  }
});
```

Here is a working example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/mustafa-agha/pen/WNRgpRB?editors=1010)

To check if the code working or not just change the if condition to be the opposite by adding an exclamation **!** to the following `(!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/))`

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative for 'autoplay'.

```js
$("document").ready(() => {
  $("#vid").play()
})
```

```html
<video muted autoplay playsinline src="path_to_video.mp4" id="vid"></video>
```

This should automatically run the video when the document loads. This should work on all browsers and IE versions higher than 9.0.

Comment: On Safari browsers, the `play()` function would only work by an user gesture(by `onclick` or using event listeners). The given example won’t work. Also, I meant to play the video when scrolled to the element, which is what `autoplay` exactly does.